# Warning: require(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, laravel, require

just moved over my laravel site to my live server and straight away faced with this error.

The complete error is:

```
Warning: require(/var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

The line 17 is:

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

Folder structure is:

```
beta.buildsanctuary.com
  -- public_html
  -- subdomains
    -- beta
      -- local
        -- bootstrap
        -- vendor
```

Any help where this is going wrong? And how to fix? Pulling my hair out trying all sorts of paths.

Thanks, Craig.

Comment: Have you verified that the hosting server's user has permissions to access all of your site's files?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Fix the path.

Comment: Have you tried php artisan dump-autoload ? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#development-workflow

Answer (score 12):

I strongly believe that a corrupted cache was the cause, I cannot be 100% sure but it seem that it is likely the culprit.

So, if anyone comes across a similar problem, I would suggest the following steps:

1. Delete the **vendor** folder
2. Delete **composer.lock**
3. Run the command `composer clearcache` (or clear-cache)
4. Run `composer install`

I hope this can help somebody.

Comment: I was running on composer version 1 and after ran `composer selfupdate` I got version 2 which was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the error, PHP is looking for

```
public_html/local/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php`
```

which is

```
public_html/local/vendor/autoload.php
```

That folder does not exist. I think the folder structure you posted is wrong.

Anyway, try this:

```
require('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Same error but just with the changed path. Have read somewhere its to do with composer not being installed correctly on my live server etc. Shall look into that route.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and it was that Composer was not installed yet in the server, so the directories structure it creates on your project does not exist neither.

First you have to install composer on your server, follow the instructions for your system given at the composer project webpage, https://getcomposer.org/.

Next you have to go in a terminal or cmd to the base folder of your project.

There you can use the commandline composer init, wich will guide you to create your composer.json file into your project.

Once you have created your composer.json file, you have to execute the commandline composer install.

This commandline will create all the dependencies you have written on your composer.json, and also will create the folder structure so the code you require would find the proper path.

At last, you have to reference the redirection to the folder vendor depending on the current folder structure location of your php file.

If you look for information, http://www.phptherightway.com/ was really helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following command, it will automatically install necessary dependencies:

composer install

Comment: run composer from which directory?

Comment: @iewebguy in the project root directory

Answer (score 0):

try disable extension=sockets in php.ini

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I have had migrated a drupal website to new server...
To solve the problem I just used the composer command:

1. First cd into website directory, EX:
   `cd /var/www/your_website`
2. Run composer to install drupal 8 dependencies that it's need in the website directory;

`composer install`

If you use the sudo command, make sure the `.../vendor` directory has the right permission to be accessed by the user who in the `/var/www`directory;

`sudo composer install`

This basically will solve the `.../public_html/autoload.php on line 14` issue!

Comment: It is not advised to run composer as sudo